# ios Mutable array

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hello everyone I am a fresher to iOS. My question is:

I have an Mutable array and a table view.
The count of the number of rows in table view is the count of the array.
If I type anything in the last row, a new row would be created.
What I want to achieve is that, if any of the row is left blank, that row should be deleted automatically.
Thanks in advance

```
@interface SubClassCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate>{
    UILabel *lblShowFirst;
    UITextField *txtShow;
    id<SubclassDelegate> delegate;
    NSArray *arrayFirstSection;
    NSArray *arraySecondSection;
    UILabel *lblShowSecond;

}   

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *lblShowFirst;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *lblShowSecond;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtShow;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SubclassDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayFirstSection;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arraySecondSection;

-(void) setCellTable:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath;

@end

@protocol SubclassDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)getTxtField:(NSString *)txtValue;
-(void)insertNewRows:(UITextField *)textF;
-(void)removeNewRows:(UITextField *)textF;


@end


subclass.m






- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [txtShow resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
    if([textField.text length] == 1)

        [self.delegate insertNewRows:textField];

    else if ([textField.text length]==2){
        [self.delegate removeNewRows:textField];

    }

        //if([textField.text length]==0){
//          [self.delegate removeNewRows:textField];
//      }

    return YES;
}





Main class.m



-(void)insertNewRows:(UITextField *)textF
{       

    [arrayTagFirst addObject:textF.text];
    [tableNewContactFirst beginUpdates];
    [tableNewContactFirst insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath                                           ndexPathForRow:[arrayTagFirst count]-1 inSection:0]]                                                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     [tableNewContactFirst endUpdates];
    if (textF.editing && textF.text==0) {
        [arrayTagFirst removeLastObject];
        [tableNewContactFirst beginUpdates];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you delete rows in UITableView

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

also you need to delete it from the NSMutableArray

```
[yourMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath];
```

to get indexPath of the empty cell, you need to add some code so that i can figure that out. It seems you have a UITextField added to each cell, let me know about the same so that i can help you out. Hope it helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: can you be more specific as to in which scenario you want the row to be deleted?

Comment: ya i want to delete the row when it is empty ..please refer to the one in contacts application the same i want to do ..i have to create a new row when i start editing in a row and i want to delete it when it is empty..please check the contacts in iphone ..